# Advanced List usage (filter enumerable items)

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox

I have a ListBox in my App. Also I have a collection of the items and each of this items have the collection of the items inside. So, actually it's a tree and I want to display them like folders/files.

```
class item
{
 ...
 List<item> childItems;
}
```

There are different types of items, some of them is not folders or files and I do not want to display them (all of them have the same base type).

So, I'm new in c#, but I feel that there should be the way to filter the items at runtime. Maybe when ListBox is trying to get the items from the List and fill itself, because I heard a little about the enumerable arrays in c#.

In c++ I fill the ListCtrl manually, but in c# there is a binding and it's cool. Currently I copy the items to ObservableCollection, filter the unwanted items and then use this collection as itemsSouce with ListBox. Maybe there is another way to filter items at runtime? I think that I should deliver my own List from the c# List and do something with enumerable interface, yep?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly your filtering logic looks like but you could create a filtered property that you bind to like this...

```
class item
{
   ...
   List<item> childItems;

    public IEnumerable<item> FileSystemItems
    {
        get
        {
            return childItems.Where(x => x is IFile || x is IFolder);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: WP7.1 doesn't have IEnumerable.Where**

I've hand edited this and can't compile it so bear with me... but wihtout using .Where it could look something like this...

```
    public List<item> FileSystemItems
    {
        get
        {
            var list = new List<item>();
            foreach (child in childItems)
            {
                if (child is IFile || child is IFolder)
                    list.Add(child);
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
```

Obviously replace IFile and IFolder with whatever your actual filter strategy looks like.

Your listbox binding will look something like this...  (this is WPF but as far as I know silverlight is the same)

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FileSystemItems}">
```

My full WPF binding looks like this..

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FileSystemItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You'll need to replace the... `{Binding Name}` part... replace `Name` with whatever property you want to display in your listbox... or you can leave that off if you aren't using an ItemTemplate.

Comment: How FileSystemItemse will be called by ListBox? It looks like I should call it and pass to ListBox by self.

Comment: So, it will not create new list as I see?

Comment: List.Where is not supported in Windows Phone 7.1 :( Only Wp8. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for update, however it's the same method that I use now (as I wrote in question). I want to avoid copying.